# How to get a Javascript routine to NOT act if it's in a text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a simple page, and in that page runs a simple jquery keypress routine to catch clicks of the numbers 1 to 9 (has to be that to pass RNIB accessibility test).

And in that page is a form, which can have numbers entered as part of a postcode.

http://find.talking-newspapers.co.uk/result.php?addressInput=kingston

Scroll to the bottom, try typing 8 or 9 for example. The text is entered, but it also acts on the keypress. Expected, but not good.

I'm aware of various things like document.getElementById, but I can't figure out how to put these together to ensure that while the cursor is in the text input box, it doesn't act out the keypress catcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `target` property of the event object (the parameter to the handler function) will tell you which element actually generated the event.

You need to check whether `e.target` is an `<input>` element, like this:

```
if ($(e.target).is(':input'))
    return;
```

Comment: Thank you - wish I could vote up, but anyway, such a simple solution, and thank you. I was far, far off the mark!

But before, I had this code, and problems:

if (evt) 
                { 
                        keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
                } 

Now I have this code, and no problems!

if (evt) 
                { 
                if ($(evt.target).is(':input'))
                return;

                        keyCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which; 
                } 

Thank you. I was looking in very much the wrong area!